# Edit the x-axis ticks in Stata

Tags: graph, stata

Without using the graph editor, I would like to know if the there is a way (code-wise) to customize with string characters the tick labels in your output graph. Say, for instance, I have four ticks in my x-axis (the following years): 2010, 2011, 2012 and 2013. If I wanted to add a character such as "#" in each year of the x-axis (e.g. each year would look something like "2010#" in the x-axis), would it be possible to do it without using the graph editor?

Comment: See `help axis_options` and `help mylabels`, the second from SSC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Roberto Ferrer's helpful comment, here is his second method based on downloading `mylabels` using `ssc inst mylabels`:

```
. webuse grunfeld, clear

. su y

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
        year |       200      1944.5    5.780751       1935       1954

. mylabels 1935(4)1955, suffix(#) myscale(@) local(lbl)
1935 "1935#" 1939 "1939#" 1943 "1943#" 1947 "1947#" 1951 "1951#" 1955 "1955#"

. xtline invest, overlay xla(`lbl')
```

It's not especially time- or effort-saving interactively, but could be built into programs or do-files.

Comment: But if I were to give a different specific character for every tick? Would that be possible?

Comment: If you want to specify a different character for each tick, you have to specify that somehow to Stata. It's difficult for me to imagine a program to specify those instructions that could be easier to use than typing those details directly as part of an axis label option. Naturally if you wanted to do that repeatedly then you could put code in a do file or write your own program. Any way, `mylabels` can't do that; it could in principle be extended to do that, but no enthusiasm from its author. More specifically, if you can give a concrete example, there might be a trick, but no promises.